# Tracking shared custom metrics from api responses with locust

Tags: python, performance, load, performance-testing, locust

I am running a locust test for testing latencies for an api under certain load. The api returns a certain count “token_spend” as part of the response and I need to aggregate all the token_spend values across all the concurrent calls (so the total token spend value could be global in this case). At the end of the test I need to record the total token spend per minute rate and compare the latencies for different set of token spend values. How should i achieve this with locust?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of custom metrics manually and use [Events](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.worker_report) to include them in the workers' reports to the master. You can then have the master pull them out when reported and include them in your terminal output or however else you want to report it.

The Locust repo has an example of this here:

https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/908c414dc04c12315ca5ecfd7851c9e42b2713ba/examples/events.py#L48

```
stats = {"content-length": 0}


@events.init.add_listener
def locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    """
    We need somewhere to store the stats.
    On the master node stats will contain the aggregated sum of all content-lengths,
    while on the worker nodes this will be the sum of the content-lengths since the
    last stats report was sent to the master
    """
    if environment.web_ui:
        # this code is only run on the master node (the web_ui instance doesn't exist on workers)
        @environment.web_ui.app.route("/content-length")
        def total_content_length():
            """
            Add a route to the Locust web app, where we can see the total content-length
            """
            return "Total content-length received: %i" % stats["content-length"]a


@events.request.add_listener
def on_request(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, exception, context, **kwargs):
    """
    Event handler that get triggered on every request.
    """
    stats["content-length"] += response_length


@events.report_to_master.add_listener
def on_report_to_master(client_id, data):
    """
    This event is triggered on the worker instances every time a stats report is
    to be sent to the locust master. It will allow us to add our extra content-length
    data to the dict that is being sent, and then we clear the local stats in the worker.
    """
    data["content-length"] = stats["content-length"]
    stats["content-length"] = 0


@events.worker_report.add_listener
def on_worker_report(client_id, data):
    """
    This event is triggered on the master instance when a new stats report arrives
    from a worker. Here we just add the content-length to the master's aggregated
    stats dict.
    """
    stats["content-length"] += data["content-length"]
```

In case it's not clear, `data` is a dictionary and you can add whatever you want to it and it will be passed to the master. Your custom data can be in whatever structure you want, but if you're dealing with anything more than a single custom value it's probably easiest to keep it in a dictionary. For example, you could either use a single variable `token_spend` as an int that sums the total of all response, or it could be a dictionary where you keep track of each endpoint that returned a number, like `token_spend = {"/some/url": 1}`.